# near "None":syntax error when running the python program

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I am dynamically creating models in sqlite3 database based on excel data.I am reading the excel data using pandas readexcel() method. When i run the program system is showing the error 'near "None":syntax error'.

---

**Error message**
OperationalError at /home/
near "None": syntax error
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:61157/home/
Django Version: 1.11.13
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
near "None": syntax error
Exception Location: C:\Users\1297805\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 326
Python Executable:  C:\Users\1297805\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardEnv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:
['C:\Users\1297805\Documents\Visual Studio '
 '2013\Projects\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardApplication',
 'C:\Users\1297805\Documents\Visual Studio '
 '2013\Projects\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardEnv\Scripts\python36.zip',
 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib',
 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36',
 'C:\Users\1297805\Documents\Visual Studio '
 '2013\Projects\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardEnv',
 'C:\Users\1297805\Documents\Visual Studio '
 '2013\Projects\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardApplication\DashBoardEnv\lib\site-packages']

### Server time:    Wed, 13 Jun 2018 09:08:35 -0500

**Reading excel data **

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_csv, encoding='utf-8')
    col_names = df.columns
fields = {}
for name in col_names:
    fields[name] =  models.CharField()
return create_model('userdata',fields,'startapp')
```

---

**creation of model**

```
    def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label='', module='', 
          options=None,admin_opts=None):
    class Meta:
        # Using type('Meta', ...) gives a dictproxy error during model 
        creation
           pass

    if app_label:
        # app_label must be set using the Meta inner class
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)

    # Update Meta with any options that were provided
    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}

    # Add in any fields that were provided
    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)

    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    # Create an Admin class if admin options were provided
    if admin_opts is not None:
         class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            pass
        for key, value in admin_opts:
            setattr(Admin, key, value)
        admin.site.register(model, Admin)

 return model
```

---

```
def install(model):
    from django.db import connection

    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
                return editor.create_model(model)
```

---

Why i am getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Django has changed a lot since 1.11 i would advice you to upgrade your Django to at least 2.0 as they have done thing that deprecate a lot things and fix a lot of bugs.

Comment: thats a vary bad advice. Actually django 2.0 has only few things that really `deprecated` - u can use most of django 1.11 code style with django 2.0. And this does not answer the original question.